# Output trouble with images and links in multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, image, multidimensional-array, hyperlink

I'm currently taking a PHP course which has been a strange change of pace from my usual C++ dealings. I'm currently trying to use arrays to display pictures with links attached to each image but I'm having no luck getting the proper output. I feel like I'm just making a simple mistake somewhere but I'm not sure. I've tried using a foreach statement but I don't quite understand how keys work so I defaulted to a for loop which I'm more comfortable with.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
    $ivideo = array
    (
        array
        (
        'image' => "image1.jpg",
        'link' => "link1",
        'caption' => "caption1"
        ),
        array
        (
        'image' => "image2.jpg",
        'link' => "link2",
        'caption' => "caption2"
        ),
        array
        (
        'image' => "image3.jpg",
        'link' => "link3",
        'caption' => "caption3"
        ),
        etc...
    );

    for($i = 0; $i < count($ivideo); $i++)
    {
            $image = $ivideo[$i]["image"];
            $link = $ivideo[$i]["link"];
            $caption = $ivideo[$i]["caption"];

            ?>
            <a href="<?php$link?>" target="_blank">
            <img src="<?php$image?>" alt="<?php$caption?>" />
            </a>
            <figcaption><?php$caption?></i></figcaption>
            <?php   
    }
?>
```

Every time I think I've got something working, all I get on the page is a bunch of blue s that seem to have links but they don't go anywhere.
I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but I needed to use an array somewhere on the site for the class and I figured a bunch of pictures was perfect. So I'm stuck and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `for` loop code should be

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($ivideo); $i++)
    {
            $image = $ivideo[$i]["image"];
            $link = $ivideo[$i]["link"];
            $caption = $ivideo[$i]["caption"];

            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">
            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $caption; ?>" />
            </a>
            <figcaption><?php echo $caption; ?></i></figcaption>
            <?php   
    }
```